# How to deal with situations when a view depends on multiple models in MVVM context?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, architecture

I am working on a battleship game using WPF. I am having a **Coordinate** model and the **ViewModel** which I bind with the **Grid** object. This **ViewModel** has the property of list of **Coordinate** objects and describes each as a **Border** with the **Label**.

The problem is that the data of the **Coordinate** class is not enough for my **Border** view style. It has only the **Row** and the **Column** properties but I want to also know whether it contains **Ship** and also to know if that **Ship** is **Wounded** or **Sunk**. Depending on these values I want to change the **Background** colour of my **Border** object.

---

### Scenario 1

If I bind my **Border** with the **Ship** then I will lose the binding with the **Coordinate** object (which is important and my **Border** still depends on it).

### Scenario 2

If I redefine my **ViewModel** to become 1 to 1 binding for a **Border** (number of instances of my **ViewModel** to match a number of instances of **Border** objects) then it feels a little dirty and not elegant enough. But in this case I would be able to define all the needed properties which my **Border** use and will be bound to.

### Scenario 3

If I create an additional class which would be the hybrid of **Coordinate** and **Ship** and that class will be used in a list as a **ViewModel** property and that list will be bound with my **Border**, then I see two issues:

1. The properties of this class will depend on each other. Let's
   say there will be a property **HasShip** and then it has a property
   **IsShipSunk**. But the latter one doesn't make sense when the first one
   has the value of false.
2. Somehow I need to build a way for my **Coordinate** and **Ship** class
   to communicate with that additional class so that values would be in
   sync. Feels like an extra work.

### Scenario 4

If I change my **Coordinate** model class to contain all the required properties then we are having the same issue I have described in my previous "if" (first point).

### Scenario 5

If I don't use bindings at all, then I don't know what would be the best practice (in this case) to implement the linking between my **Border** view and **Coordinate** model. Also I will need to get the **Battlefield** object where that **Coordinate** belongs to to be able to fetch all the **Ship** objects from there. And this approach feels like "Why you go for WPF if you are not using MVVM?". I have chosen WPF because I love C# and also because WPF has a great UI Controls architecture.

I am pretty much aware that WPF and MVVM might not be suitable for games like this one and it is designed for different purposes. But I still would like find a nice neat solution in case it exists.

---

So, in a nutshell: how to build the following:

1. The user clicks on the **Border** (looks like a cell)
2. The corresponding **Coordinate** object is fetched
3. The corresponding **Battlefield** where that **Coordinate** belongs to
   is fetched
4. The iteration of **Ship** objects is performed to check if any of
   them contain that coordinate
5. Depending on the result change the colour of my **Border**
   **Background** (**Blue** - when missed, **Orange** - when hit, **Black** - when the
   **Ship** is sunk (please, note, I want **all** the related **Border** objects to change
   the colour from **Orange** to **Black** when the **Ship** has sunk))

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you chose that particular representation (list of ships) for your game state for a good reason, you should not change it for the UI presentation. What you do in the View should theoretically not influence you to change the Model.

Number 3 is the solution most fitting to MVVM development. You create a real View Model wrapping your actual model.

Please do remember that you don't need to keep two states, your properties can depend on other properties and objects. You can have a reference to your ship list in the Field and generate its properties based on what it contatins, like:

```
public class Field
{
    GameStateModel GameState { get; set; }

    public int Row { get; set; }
    public int Col { get; set; }

    private Ship ShipOnField
    {
        get
        {
            return GameState.Ships.Where(s => s.Row == Row && s.Col == Col).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }

    public bool HasShip
    {
        get
        {
            return ShipOnField != null;
        }
    }

    public bool IsShipSunk
    {
        get
        {
            return ShipOnField != null && ShipOnField.Ded;
        }
    }
}
```

There are two issues with this solution though. One is performance. Other one is an issue of updating the view on changes in the model. You will either have to update everything on each change, or chain the changes in model to your ViewModel updates.